# Python os.system command not working?

Tags: python, os.system

Earlier I used to code in python well, but after I formatted my computer and reinstalled the same python setup, my `os.system` command stopped working, as well as `subprocess.Popen`.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your default shell `cmd` is broken.

Comment: hmmm...  that's strange.  It looks like you have 64bit python installed?  Are you on Win32?  Or 64?  It appears from your screenshot that you might be on a 32bit os.  Just a guess.

Comment: Do these commands work if you run them from the command line?

Comment: Have you checked your `environment variables` to make sure they are setup  correctly?

Comment: @Jakob what do you mean by cmd is broken :(

Comment: @David no i m on 64 bit windows :(

Comment: @Kevin yea these commands run perfectly wen i run from my command line

Comment: @serk yea checked the environment variables. What do you recommend to check in the environment variables??

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a path issue.  The only way I could reproduce that -1 error was by setting my path to nothing so that Python couldn't find cmd.exe.

Here's a link I ran across by searching for "set windows path" in stack exchange:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

It tells how to set it for Winddows XP, the procedure is pretty much the same in later versions in that you're basically setting up environment variables which are stored in the registry.

Comment: Set the path in the environment settings by right clicking on your computer, as he mentioned above.

See link:
http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: i have already added python to my PATH variable, that's wahy the python is running in cmd prompt

Comment: The error you're getting is either due to cmd.exe not being on path or cmd.exe is corrupted.  That -1 appears to be thrown when the os.system function can't start the cmd.exe (the shell) program.